# How to set id for AJAX

Tags: yii2-advanced-app

I have following Jquery-Script, which works fine outside of yii2

```html
        <script>
            $(function () {
                $(".comment_button").click(function () {
                    var element = $(this);
                    var test = $("#_id_").val();
                    var dataString = '_id_=' + test;
                    if (test == '')
                    {
                        alert("No record, no action...!");
                    } else
                    {
                        $.ajax({
                            type: "POST",
                            url: '<?=\Yii::$app->urlManager->baseUrl?>/insert.php',
                            //url: 'insert.php',
                            data: dataString,
                            cache: false,
/*
                            success: function (html) {
                                $("#display").after(html);
                                document.getElementById('_id_').value = '';
*/
                            }
                        });
                    }
                    return false;
                });
            });
        </script>
```

It works,'cause I have following html input box:

```
<textarea cols="30" rows="2" style="width:480px;font-size:14px; font-weight:bold" id="_id_" maxlength="145" ></textarea>
```

As u can see, jquery will take id= _ id _ in order to use AJAX.
I try to realize same thing with yii2, but I get following error:

```html
bewerber_update?id=2:1925 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'value' of null
    at Object.success (bewerber_update?id=2:1925)
    at fire (jquery.js:3187)
    at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (jquery.js:3317)
    at done (jquery.js:8757)
    at XMLHttpRequest.<anonymous> (jquery.js:9123)
```

This error will be thrown out,' cause I don't konw, how to set id correctly in yii2. I tried like this, but this is obviously the wrong way:

```html
    <?=
    $form->field($model, 'beurteilung_fachlich')->widget(\dosamigos\ckeditor\CKEditor::className(), [
        'id'=>'_id_',
        'options' => ['rows' => 1],
        'preset' => 'full'
    ])
    ?>
```

Any ideas, how to set id in a correct way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should pass `id` in `options`

```
<?= $form->field($model, 'beurteilung_fachlich')->widget(\dosamigos\ckeditor\CKEditor::className(), [
    'options' => ['rows' => 1, 'id' => '_id_'],
    'preset' => 'full'
]) ?>
```